# Recommendations for hosting Rails on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, chef

There are a number of solutions for easily hosting Rails on Amazon EC2 like the following

1. [Poolparty](https://github.com/auser/poolparty)
2. [Rubber](https://github.com/wr0ngway/rubber)
3. [Amazon Cloud Formation](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/)
4. [Opscode Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/)
5. Rolling your own

(and I'm sure others I'm not aware of) and I'd love some guidance on which route to go.
This will be a small setup with one MySQL db and two app servers and then hopefully growing from there. The last thing I want to do is re-invent the wheel and roll my own setup so solutions like Poolparty and Rubber are appealing but I've never used them.

I know there's also Heroku and EngineYard and I've used both in the past but they just use Amazon EC2 behind the scenes, so I'd rather just go with a solution that's straight up Amazon EC2.

Any recommendations on which route to go would be great!

Comment: One option I'm looking at now is http://scalr.net which is free for up to 8 EC2 servers and has a pretty easy system to get a vanilla rails app up and running quickly

Comment: We should make sure that this is as clear as possible. What you're asking is not necessarily how to *host* Rails on EC2, but how to manage EC2 instances that should be configured to run a Rails application stack.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites because of their very limited lifespan. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Chef it's a simple, but powerful solution for managing EC2 machines... (any machine in that case)

Plus your already finished, opscode has some cookbooks for mysql and rails:

http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/mysql

http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/rails

Here's a bootstrap command after you get your chef server and git repo running:

```
knife ec2 server create -G default -x ec2-user -S id_rsa -I ami-2a1fec43 -f m1.small -i .ssh/id_rsa.pem -d fedora13-gems
```

I use a custom amazon bootstrap file, but the fedora13-gems bootstrap files works fine and is bundled with chef/knife already.